# Zend Authentication 'Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable' gives error while authenticating

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I used a simple instruction from
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html#advanced-usage-by-example for Zend Authentication.

Here is my code:

```
$adapter = $sm->get('adapter');
$authAdapter = new DbTable($adapter);
$authAdapter -> setTableName('users')->setIdentityColumn('username')->setCredentialColumn('password');
$authAdapter -> setIdentity('admin')-> setCredential('password');
$authAdapter -> authenticate();
```

The above code generates error as follows:
The supplied parameters to DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.

I know if makes sense to use ZF-Commons and ZF-Users module and not reinvent the wheel... but being relatively new to ZF2 I want to try it myself.

Comment: Have you created the users table in your database?

Comment: @Ezequiel - yup, I have created a simple users table. The $adapter is all okay, I tried by listing all the users of the table. Here is the snapshot of the users table. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9au01uwlz2egfzr/shot_130516_130443.png I hope I have not done anything silly.

Comment: Maybe use the `$adapter->getDbSelect();` method to see what the SQL looks like?

Comment: Hi again, $authAdapter->getDbSelect()->getSqlString() generated an empty string...

Comment: The problem is solved by downloading the latest version Zend Framework 2.2.0. http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest 

I guess the version I was using, ZF 2.1.0 had a bug. Anyway, I am now using the new version and I dont have any problem. thank you all for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer's right there in the error message, `Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable` expects more than just an adapter as a parameter, it also needs a table name, and the name of the identifier and credential columns...

```
$authAdapter = new DbTable($dbAdapter,
                           'tableName',
                           'identifierColumnName',
                           'credentialColumnName'
                           );
```

This info is covered in the docs, which is always a good starting point -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html

Comment: He is in fact setting those required parameters using setter methods.

Comment: yup, @Crisp. I have set those params from the setter methods.

Comment: heh, early morning, I see that after a coffee or two :o), does it work if you don't use the setter methods and instantiate with params instead?

Comment: Hi, I tried by passing the params in the constructor. The result is always the same as using the setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one and probably you have the answer now. Even though, I will put my answer here for further users. I myself faced lots of similar issues where the tutorials expect us to have some preconditions in place.

This error occur because you are not completely right in the statement to get the DB adapter. You need to call a service management instance with an string defined in your locals or globals configurations. For example:

I have this factory defined in my global.php file:

```
    return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
);
```

In my local.php I have the credentials and information to reach my DB server as follow:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'valid_dbusername',
        'password' => 'valid_dbpass',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=valid_dbname;host=valid_dbserver',
    ),
);
```

This is enough to define my service calle 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'. Then, to instantiate my Db adapter I have the following lines inside any function in my controller:

```
if (!$this->adapter) {
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
}
```

It is important to note adapter here is a class variable. So, it must be defined inside my controller class like:

```
public $adapter;
```

This steps are enough to you get an DB adapter. I am assuming you dont have a factory called 'adapter'. This should make your example work.